# Closure of the rationals in the cocountable topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I’m trying to find the closure of the rationals in the co countable topology, however I am unable to move forward with this problem. I’m stuck at finding the limit points of the rationals. I know that $x$ is a limit point of the rationals iff every set with a countable complement intersects the rationals excluding the point. So I’m not sure how to proceed using $\textbf{limit points}$. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, we have that $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is open, so its complement, which is $\Bbb Q$ again, is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has as its closed sets $\mathbb{R}$ and all countable (including finite) sets.

So the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, a countable set, is just $\mathbb{Q}$ by definition; a closed set is its own closure.